# Apache Jena Query Execution Time

Tags: jena, apache-jena

So I have this piece of code in Jena, that measures the execution time of a select query

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.startTimer();
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query,dataset);
ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();

long endTime = timer.endTimer();
```

Now the issue is the that this variable `endTime` shows a running time result that is smaller than what the query execution time should have been. The `dataset` is a Jena TDB location.

To test this out, I ran the same query using Apache Jena's Fuseki on the same TDB store and I find that the execution time is different (maybe the actual execution time). What is the right way to find execution time using Jena. I don't want to execute everything using Fuseki and find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QueryExecutionFactory.create(query,dataset);
```

All this does is create an execution that can execute your query, importantly it **does not** execute your query.

To **start** execution you need to call one of the `execX()` methods which will depend on the query type e.g. `execSelect()` for `SELECT` queries

Execution in Jena is lazy so in order to time execution you need to actually enumerate the results, execution does not **finish** until results are fully enumerated e.g.

```
ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
long numResults = ResultSetFormatter.consume(results);
```

And at that point you can stop your timer

Comment: Thank you @RobV. I realized I did not add the execSelect() part, which I had in my code. Added that to the question. But I did not know about the consume part.